# AngularJS error module with minified scripts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify

I create my application using AngularJS. Lately, I tried to add minified scripts to project. I configured my bundles and add there scripts.

Unfortunately, after getting on my page, I saw error in console:

```
angularjs?v=DPp8dw32SOYLsCU70JJTuQ_I9tbCvN1g_Jgbcn9Mnx01:1 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error
```

... I read about problem with minified scripts from: [http://frontendcollisionblog.com](http://frontendcollisionblog.com/javascript/angularjs/2015/03/31/something-no-one-tells-you-about-minifying-angularjs-controllers-until-its-too-late.html)
but I did not found it in my project. Have you got any idea what can be wrong with it?

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.bootstrap", "schemaForm"]);
MyApp.requires.push("ngFileUpload");
MyApp.config([
'$compileProvider', '$sceDelegateProvider', '$httpProvider',
function ($compileProvider, $sceDelegateProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|sip|chrome-extension):/);
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        window.AppData.scriptsCdnEndpoint + '/**'
    ]);
    $httpProvider.defaults.cache = true;
}
```

]);
`

Comment: * What do you use for minification?
* How do you describe your module? Show pls example.

Comment: For minification I use `EnableOptimizations` and `UseCdn` property. I added module definition in main post

Comment: No idea what is going wrong. Have 2 suggestions to try. 1. Move to the original array (ngFileUpload) to the module declaration. 2 Try to remove 3rd party dependencie and check whether minification will work. At least you will find the source.

Comment: @Drag13 thank you for answer. After changes nothing has changed

Comment: Add ngFileUpload as module dependency & remove it as: `MyApp.requires.push("ngFileUpload");` . Instead have : `var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.bootstrap", "schemaForm", "ngFileUpload"]);` and have `<script src="ng-file-upload(.min).js"></script>` in index.html follow docs: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: Add `ngFileUpload` as module dependency didn't help